# Can't inspect Swift variables in LLDB when running on device

Tags: swift, lldb

If I try to print a variable in lldb with `po self`, for example, I get:

```
(lldb) po self
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  __TMC4skyq12BlahBlahBlah
```

In fact, I literally can't evaluate / print anything from lldb:

```
(lldb) expression "Hello World!"
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  __TMC4skyq12BlahBlahBlah
(lldb) p "Hello World!"
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  __TMC4skyq12BlahBlahBlah
```

How can I fix this? I'm using: Xcode 7.3 (7D175).

## Observations

- This only seems to happen when I run on the physical device. On the simulator, the error doesn't happen.
- I've also created an empty standard project, and inspection works fine in this.
- It only happens in the Swift parts of the codebase. If I have a breakpoint in obj-c code, lldb is able to print symbols from there.

Comment: It's strange because I every day use `po` and it works. In latest XCode it even has autocompletion for Swift.

Comment: It is strange! I'm sure I've seen it work, and it does work in obj-c code. But I've also seen it not work at other times, and Google hasn't lead me to a solution or even howls of annoyance at it not working, which seems surprising for such a fundamental tool.

Comment: maybe it has some issue with the indexing of the project, did it happen in all the project or only this project only ?

Comment: Hey, good idea – I've just tried a restart. I'll try a clean and see if that helps…

Comment: Nope, still not working.

Comment: Okay. What is `self` in your example? If you try to inspect other variables, does it work?

Comment: If you have a project which reproduces this every time, I'd recommend [filing a Radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: I just tried a new project, and it doesn't happen in that. However – I have noticed that it only happens when I'm running on my test device. It doesn't happens in the simulator.

Comment: I think self in the current frame is not captured (e.g. inside a closure). That's why it can't be looked up. Try sharing the code around your breakpoint frame.

Comment: One concern that I have is that __TMC4skyqBlahBlahBlah is *NOT* a valid Swift mangled name - it would have to be __TMC4skyq12BlahBlahBlah (notice the extra '12' before the class name)

Comment: @EnricoGranata :-) Thanks, that is the form of the symbol name. I'll fix it.

Comment: Try downloading the Xcode 7.3.1 GM. It may fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure why you're seeing those errors, I've not been the biggest fan of **llvm + Swift** as I've found it produces long object metadata rather than calling the `description` method.

I've found `e print(<object>)` to work more in keeping with what I'm used to with **llvm + objective-c**

This is equivalent to the normal Swift `print` method; the `e` is an llvm command to `e`xecute the command.

Comment: Thanks James. In this case, the `e` llvm command gives the same error. Even something like `e print("Hello World!")` gives the error.